# Can't submit form data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I cant get vars in php file. Echo returns nothing and I can't make a query.
Please help me. I know there is few stupid mistakes, but I'm really tired to search it..

I have a form:

```
<form align="center" method="POST" action="saveuser.php">
<small>Choose person:</small>
<select name="user" id="user" size="1" onchange="loadUserData()">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        if (!$con) {
            die('Connection error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo 'Connection Success';
        mysql_select_db("live", $con);

        $sql_query="SELECT name,id FROM res1";
        if(!mysql_query($sql_query, $con))
        {
            die('INSERT Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $query = mysql_query($sql_query, $con);
        $max_row=0;

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            if ($max_row !=0){
                echo "<option value={$row[id]}>{$row[name]}</option>";
            }
            $max_row=1;
        }

        mysql_close($con);
    ?>
</select></br>
<input id="id" type="hidden"/>
<small>Name: </small><input id="name" type="text" size="40" /> 
<small>Nat: </small><input id="nat" type="text" size="30" />
<small>Licence: </small><input id="licence" type="text" size="10" /></br>
<small>R1: </small><input id="r1" type="text" size="5" />
<small>R2: </small><input id="r2" type="text" size="5" />
<small>R3: </small><input id="r3" type="text" size="5" />
<small>R4: </small><input id="r4" type="text" size="5" />
<small>R5: </small><input id="r5" type="text" size="5" />
<small>R6: </small><input id="r6" type="text" size="5" />
<small>R7: </small><input id="r7" type="text" size="5" /></br>
<small>FO1: </small><input id="f1" type="text" size="5" />
<small>FO2: </small><input id="f2" type="text" size="5" />
<small>FO3: </small><input id="f3" type="text" size="5" /></br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
```

And php file saveuser.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con) {
    die('Connection error: ' . mysql_error());
}
//echo 'Connection Success';
mysql_select_db("live", $con);

$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
echo $id;
echo $name;

$sql_query="UPDATE res1 SET name='".$name."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
//,nat,licence,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,f1,f2,f3 FROM res1 WHERE id='$value'";
$query = mysql_query($sql_query, $con);

mysql_close($con);

//$URL="edit.php";
//header ("Location: $URL");
```

?>

Comment: I tried to run php file. No errors. But "echo $id;" return nothing..

Comment: Your queries may not be returning anything, so, that would be the first place.. check the query string you make, run it in mysql yourself, see what results are present.

Comment: ID has no value... you just set it as <input id="id" type="hidden"/>   .. what value did you expect it to have? isnt it name="id" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are not setting the name of the fields, `id` does not replace `name`:

```
<small>Name: </small><input name="name" id="name" type="text" size="40" /> 
<small>Nat: </small><input name="nat" id="nat" type="text" size="30" />
// etc ...
```

Comment: "`id` does not replace `name`" …for form inputs; for anchors on the other hand it is a replacement; maybe the OP gets confused a bit with that fact;

Answer (score 2):

You have not given your inputs a `name` attribute.

Your `$_POST` array will only contain values for the ones that do.

Answer (score 1):

try input submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

then close the form

and give a name to the inputs